# Solrj timeout on Railo

Tags: solr, solrj, railo, coldbox, javaloader

We are getting a timeout when trying to do a solrj update to a remote solr server running solr 4.0. The server we are using to do the update is a Railo Apache Tomcat server running Railo version 3.3.5.002 and Windows 2008 R2.

We are using ColdBox's javaloader to instantiate the required jars. We feel that something is happening on Railo to cause this timeout; however we have not been able to trace it down. Here is a link to the stackstrace for the timeout.

http://pastebin.com/pBSmV0cT

The jars that we are using
apache-solr-solrj-4.0.0-ALPHA.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-io-2.1.jar
httpclient-4.1.3.jar
httpcore-4.1.4.jar
httpmime-4.1.3.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
tika-app-1.2.jar
wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar

Comment: What does the Solr log file say? I mean, if you have a timeout on the client side, you should check the server log file and see if requests are coming, if there is some kind of error.

Comment: That timeout is a Railo one, so in addition to checking the Solr logs, you could also just try increasing the request timeout in Railo Admin (Settings>Application) and seeing if this allows Solrj to eventually complete.